# verificar firma N509 en archivo xml con c#

Tags: c#, xml

Yo de vuelta con otro problema de xml. Ayer un chico del chat me ayudó con lo que era la verificación de la firma RSA y quedó todo bien...para el día de hoy estoy con la verificación de firma N509.

estoy usando el ejemplo de esta página de Microsoft -> [X509IssuerSerial Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.x509issuerserial?view=netcore-2.2)

Al igual que ayer, comento que este documento xml está firmado con RSA y N509, este es el código correspondiente de cómo se ve:

```html
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
   <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
   <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <Reference URI="">
    <Transforms>
     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>udepTY+WwuVOwC1RwYaIvKFWNrE=</DigestValue>
   </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>HMam8utDpTMT+hXyQKkYAP8MXB+UjKOu4QF7z7LcTiXd6Rh5TdsB51xg5PLTLIgv8NHZLTxLJesQtpFXHJH5qe4JgslzyQGfeQXEVSouRiLrP5P+ASVpxGqMdhXf6UtQuGCMT+nrs07Z0NSwvyUqkM1TLbnMVqSr04l6M8ExpHY=</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
   <KeyValue>
    <RSAKeyValue>
     <Modulus>wx8+h5ym+bvtyV4lBKyJxOcItdzNphFMN4Ol9x2IRVpyJmWm+nsFJpRYPg1f6punl0sXR4ELFBUg2ktprHS26Aj2CHwzcKmn6OCJeFvVPLItwa9XPo6bZ/EZiXXCK+KI23tZDnEfKuf3jiqWOMpZSNsMfzGO8uqsqvrYuyBwFdE=</Modulus>
     <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>
   </KeyValue>
   <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
   </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
 </Signature>
```

Este es el código que encontré que verifica el certificado N509:

```html
public static Boolean VerifyXmlFile(String FileName, String CertificateSubject)
{
       X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBySubject(CertificateSubject);
       XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDocument.Load(FileName);
       SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);
       XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
       signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
       return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
}
```

Y este es el que hace referencia para ir a buscar el Certificado:

```html
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateBySubject(string CertificateSubject)
        {
            // Check the args.
            if (null == CertificateSubject)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("CertificateSubject");


            // Load the certificate from the certificate store.
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;

            X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            try
            {
                // Open the store.
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                // Get the certs from the store.
                X509Certificate2Collection CertCol = store.Certificates;

                // Find the certificate with the specified subject.
                foreach (X509Certificate2 c in CertCol)
                {
                    if (c.Subject == CertificateSubject)
                    {
                        cert = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Throw an exception of the certificate was not found.
                if (cert == null)
                {
                    throw new CryptographicException("The certificate could not be found.");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the store even if an exception was thrown.
                store.Close();
            }

            return cert;
        }
```

Comprobé que la función que va a buscar el certificado funciona, pero es la otra la que me trae problemas. También comentar que dentro del firmado de ejemplo que tiene la página omití 4 lineas,son estas:

```html
X509IssuerSerial xserial;
xserial.IssuerName = cert.IssuerName.ToString(); 
xserial.SerialNumber = cert.SerialNumber;
kdata.AddIssuerSerial(/*xserial.IssuerName, */xserial.SerialNumber);
```

Las tenga o no en mi firma me tiran error, también he buscado ejemplos de documentos firmados y en ninguno he visto que tengan estos datos.

Si alguien me puede guiar para entender donde tengo el error se lo agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Veo que en un solo xml lo estas firmando con `RSA` y luego con `X509`, no se si ya realizaste la prueba de solo firmar el `XML` con `X509` y luego validar la firma. Si te funciona, entonces el problema esta en como agregas las dos firmas al documento.

Comment: voy aprobar lo que dices, gracias

Comment: Es que segun el enlace que dejas en tu pregunta [x509issuerserial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.x509issuerserial?view=netcore-2.2) tienen un ejemplo completo, por lo que hay que suponer ese ejemplo funciona, tambien puedes crearte un proyecto aparte de pruebas y copias y pegas el mismo codigo de ejemplo que muestran y solo reemplaza el subject del certificado y el localstore por los tuyos solo como modo de pruebas.

Comment: voy a hacer la prueba y comento acá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal Sebastian pensaba hacer varios comentarios a tu codigo pero mejor te agrego un ejemplo de firmado de documento (use la hora de comida para hacer esta prueba asi que esta algo desordenado y como veras algunos nombres de variables se pueden mejorar)

creas una clase publica RSA_Helper:

```
 public class RSA_helper
    {
       public static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate(string certPath,string password)
        {
             X509Certificate2  certificado= new X509Certificate2();
            certificado.Import(ReadFile(certPath),password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            return certificado;
        }
        internal static byte[] ReadFile(string fileName)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int size = (int)f.Length;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            size = f.Read(data, 0, size);
            f.Close();
            return data;
        }

    }
```

en la clase Program agregue dos metodos una de Firmado

```
 private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument,string pathCert,string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
        {


            XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
            documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

            SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

            var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
            firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
            firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

            //digest info agregada en la seccion firma
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            reference.Uri = "";
            firmado.AddReference(reference);

            reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

            firmado.AddReference(reference);

            // info para la llave publica 
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
            firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;


            firmado.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();
            documentXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(documentXml.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
            //guardando salida.
            documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);
        }
```

en la parte de Verificacion de firma:

```
   private static bool  VerificarFirma(string pathXmlSigned,string pathCert,string passCert)
        {
            var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
           var key= (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
            XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
            documentXml.Load(pathXmlSigned);

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(documentXml);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = documentXml.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

          return   signedXml.CheckSignature(key);
        }
```

en el metodo Main

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //parametros
            string pathXmlDocument = @".\CreditCardInfo.xml";
            string pathXmlSignedDocument= @".\CreditCardInfoSigned.xml";
            string pathCertificate = @".\zarateCert.pfx";
            string certPassword = "zarateTest";

            FirmarDocumento(pathXmlDocument, pathCertificate, certPassword, pathXmlSignedDocument);


           var esValido=    VerificarFirma(pathXmlSignedDocument, pathCertificate, certPassword);

        }
```

es todo realice varias pruebas  y todo bien.

Nota1: Para cuando tengas tu certificado asegurate que tengas tambien la llave privada (pfx), agrego comandos para generacion de certificados de prueba:

```
makecert.exe -r -n “CN=zarateCert” -pe -sv zarateCert.pvk -a sha1 -len 2048 -b 01/01/2015 -e 01/01/2030 -cy authority zarateCert.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk zarateCert.pvk -spc zarateCert.cer -pfx zarateCert.pfx -po Secreto01
```

Comment: pero si ves que tengo algún error en mi código o si se puede mejorar dime, si quiero aprender a hacer esto bien y llevo varios días pegado con esto. Voy a probar tu código y te aviso. Gracias

Comment: te comento que esos comandos no lo toma mi pc, así que voy a buscar otra forma de generar un certificado y llave privada

Comment: Se debe a que esos antes venian por default en windows pero los pudes obtener instalando el SDK de windows o simplemente descargalos de [sinigning tools](https://github.com/3gstudent/signtools), los pegas en la carpeta donde quieras generar tu certificado.

Comment: ok, bueno encontré un documento y creé la firma. También creé un botón para validar la firma y funciona, borré un campo del xml y anda impecable. Se que esto es tema para plantearlo en otra pregunta pero también tengo que validar este xml con su xsd. me podrías ayudar? Muchas Gracias! te pasaste

Comment: pues agrega tu pregunta y ya veremos, mientras ve estudiando el tema.